# Добавление задач в Scheduler циклом for

Tags: python, планировщик-задач

Проблема в следующем, пытаюсь в цикле for создавать динамически поступающие из сервиса задачи, но в текущем виде задача выполняется 1 раз после чего код падает, не могу понять причину. Минимально воспроизводимый кусок кода:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler


def create_task(metod):
    with open('C:/test.txt', 'a+') as test:
        test.write(
            f'Ура, сервис не упал, получен метод: {metod}\n')


def sched():
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    with open('C:/now_task.txt', 'r') as now:
        lines_now = now.readlines()
        if lines_now != []:
            for line in lines_now:
                clear_line = line.rstrip().split('|')
                if clear_line[3] == 'date':
                    queue = clear_line[0]
                    title = clear_line[1]
                    msg = clear_line[2]
                    method = clear_line[3]
                    with open('C:/test.txt', 'a+') as test:
                        test.write(
                            f'Получены параметры: {queue}, {title}, {msg}, {method}\n')
                elif clear_line[3] == 'interval':
                    queue = clear_line[0]
                    title = clear_line[1]
                    msg = clear_line[2]
                    method = clear_line[3]
                    with open('C:/test.txt', 'a+') as test:
                        test.write(
                            f'Получены параметры: {queue}, {title}, {msg}, {method}\n')
                elif clear_line[3] == 'cron':
                    queue = clear_line[0]
                    title = clear_line[1]
                    msg = clear_line[2]
                    method = clear_line[3]
                    with open('C:/test.txt', 'a+') as test:
                        test.write(
                            f'Получены параметры: {queue}, {title}, {msg}, {method}\n')
                scheduler.add_job(create_task(method), 'interval', seconds=10)
                try:
                    scheduler.start()
                except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    pass
```

файл C:/now_task.txt:

```
Параметр|тест метод Дата|текст сообщения|date
Параметр|тест метод Интервал|текст сообщения|interval
Параметр|тест метод Крон|текст сообщения|cron
```

Если вынести парсинг в функцию create_task - все работает, но в таком случае не получается передать параметры в создаваемый scheduler.

Буду крайне признателен за любую помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос так (оставлю здесь возможно кому то пригодиться):

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler


def create_task(ter, title, msg):
    with open('C:/test.txt', 'a+') as test:
        test.write(
            f'Получены данные: {ter}, {title}, {msg}\n')


def sched():
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    with open('C:/now_task.txt', 'r') as now:
        lines_now = now.readlines()
        if lines_now != []:
            for line in lines_now:
                clear_line = line.rstrip().split('|')
                if clear_line[3] == 'date':
                    queue = clear_line[0]
                    title = clear_line[1]
                    msg = clear_line[2]
                    method = clear_line[3]
                   
                    scheduler.add_job(create_task, trigger=f'{method}', seconds=10, args=[queue, title, msg]) 
                elif clear_line[3] == 'interval':
                    queue = clear_line[0]
                    title = clear_line[1]
                    msg = clear_line[2]
                    method = clear_line[3]
                    
                    scheduler.add_job(create_task, trigger=f'{method}', seconds=10, args=[queue, title, msg])
                elif clear_line[3] == 'cron':
                    queue = clear_line[0]
                    title = clear_line[1]
                    msg = clear_line[2]
                    method = clear_line[3]
                    
                    scheduler.add_job(create_task, trigger=f'{method}', seconds=10, args=[queue, title, msg])
    try:
       scheduler.start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
       pass
```